# Word problem about adding continuous random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I cannot seem to figure out how to do the following word problem:

"The amount of cereal that can be poured into a small bowl varies with a mean of 1.5 oz and a SD of 0.3 oz. A large bowl holds a mean of 2.5 oz with an SD of 0.4 ounces. You open a new box of cereal and pour one large and one small bowl...If the difference follows a Normal model, what's the probability the small bowl contains more cereal than the large one?"

My work:

S=1.5
L=2.5
D=1.5-2.5=-1 (This I assume is the mean of the new normal distribution)

In order to get the SD of the new distribution, I do sqrt(0.3^2+0.4^2)=0.5

Thus, I model the problem with N(-1, .5) and I need to find P(D is greater than zero) which I get to be about 0.107. however, the answer in my textbook says the correct answer is 0.023. Perhaps my reasoning is flawed somewhere?

Comment: Maybe we can find the error. But first let's solve the problem. We want to find the probability that a normal with mean $-1$ and standard deviation $0.5$ is greater than $0$. This is the probability that $Z\gt \frac{0-(-1)}{0.5}=2$. You can find this in the table, or using software. It is quite a bit smaller than $0.107$.

Comment: It is still not 0.023

Comment: Using a web normal table I get about $1-0.9772$, which is $0.0228$.  What did you get?

Comment: Im getting that P(Z is greater than 2) equals 1.215E-8??

Comment: Im using the ti89 and it asks for the mean, SD, and the "X Value". For the x value im plugging in 2, and it spits out the above #

Comment: I don't know how what one has to tell the TI89 to get it to compute the right thing.

Comment: @AndréNicolas what did you plug into the x-value in alpha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the amount of cereal in the small bowl, and $Y$ the amount in the large bowl. We want to find the probability that $X-Y\gt 0$.

The random variable $W=X-Y$, under our assumptions, has normal distribution mean $-1$ and standard deviation $0.5$. Thus
$$\Pr(W\gt 0)=\Pr\left(Z\gt \frac{0-(-1)}{0.5}\right)=\Pr(Z\gt 2)=1-\Pr(Z\le 2)\approx 1-0.9772.$$

Comment: Alright, when I plug in zero for the x-value, it gives me 0.107.

Comment: You can try here: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=normalpdf&a=*C.normalpdf-_*Formula.dflt-&f2=-1&f=NormalPDF.mu\u005f-1&f3=.5&f=NormalPDF.sigma\u005f.5&f4=0&f=NormalPDF.x_0)

Comment: @aronp its in the question

Comment: @quantitive rtfq, apologies.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a TI89, and hardly ever use Alpha. I asked Alpha for the probability that Z>2. It gave me the right answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas would you mind posting a link of what you plugged in? It will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can't do link, but I typed exactly probability that Z>2

Comment: [got it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%28Z%3E2%29)